# How to fix indentation problem with haskell if statement

Tags: haskell

I have the following Haskell code:

```
f :: Int -> Int
f x =
  let var1 = there in
  case (there) of
    12 -> 0 
    otherwise | (there - 1) >= 4 -> 2
              | (there + 1) <= 2 -> 3

  where there = 6
```

The function alone is garbage, ignore what exactly it does.

I want to replace the guards with if

```
f x =
  let var1 = there in
  case (there) of
    12 -> 0 
    otherwise -> if (there - 1) >= 4 then 2
                    else if (there + 1) <= 2 then 3

  where there = 6
```

I tried moving the if to the next line, the then to the next line, lining them up, unlining them, but nothing seems to work.

I get a parsing error and I don't know how to fix it:

```
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
   |
40 |   where there = 6
   |   ^
```

Comment: You need to give `else` part for `if (there + 1) <= 2 then 3` expression. In Haskell, `if` expression must have `then` and `else`.

Comment: It's a good attempt, thank you for including code.

@wizzup Why was the provided code not a MCVE in your view?  It was the code used, it has a syntax error that believably causes the parse error.  Given the asker's clear misunderstandings any further attempt to minimize probably changed the error and added to the confusion.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson, A simple re-indent show me that last `if` has no `else`. https://pastebin.com/BeeGWP9i

Comment: I'd tend to avoid using both `let` and `where`, when possible. In the code above, I'd put both definitions inside the `let` (provided you actually need those definitions).

Comment: disregarding the actual code errors in your question, purely indentation-based errors are fixed with the use of explicit markings like `{`, `;`, `|`, `}`, making the code wholly space-insensitive again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a few misunderstandings in here.  Let's step through them starting from your original code:

```
f x =
```

A function definition, but the function never uses the parameter `x`.  Strictly speaking this is a warning and not an error, but most code bases will use `-Werror` so consider omitting the parameter or using `_` to indicate you are explicitly ignoring the variable.

```
  let var1 = there in
```

This is unnecessary - again you are not using `var1` (the below used `there`) so why have it?

```
  case (there) of
```

Sure.  Or just `case there of`, not need for excessive parens cluttering up the code.

```
    12 -> 0
```

Here `12` is a pattern match, and it's fine.

```
    otherwise ->
```

Here you used the variable name `otherwise` as a pattern which will uncondtionally match the value `there`.  This is another warning: `otherwise` is a global value equal to `True` so it can be used in guards, such as `function foo | foo < 1 = expr1  ; | otherwise = expr2`.  Your use is not like that, using `otherwise` as a pattern shadows the global value.  Instead consider the catch all pattern with underscore:

```
_ -> if (there - 1) >= 4
         then 2
         else if (there + 1) <= 2
                 then 3
  where there = 6
```

Ok... what if `there` was equal to 3?  `3-1` is not greater than 4.  `3+1` is not less than 2.  You always need an `else` with your if statement.  There is no `if {}` in Haskell instead there is `if ... else ...` much like the ternary operator in C, as [explained in the Haskell wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Common_Misunderstandings#If_.2F_Then_.2F_Else).

Comment: Thanks for the code, explanation, and link. I will check it out and understand further misunderstanding. Thanks again